# How to apply a patch?

Tags: patch

I found a patch I want here:
 http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17763

I can see the *diff*, but what do I do now? How can I get that code into my Wordpress? Do I have to copy it manually? Is there anywhere to download it from?

Comment: FYI: [How to use patch command in WinSCP?](https://superuser.com/q/1629319/301042) in Super User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the diff file from the bottom of the diff page.

The program to apply a diff is called "patch". It's widely available for various platforms.

Example usages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)#Usage_examples

Comment: Thank you very much- that worked. I'm only going to add a detailed description of the steps I took:   
1) I downloaded the diff file from the bottom of the page  
2) I uploaded the file to the server, to the folder in    which the file that diff will be applied to resides in (in my case the file that the diff applied to was `comment-template.php`, which resides in `wp-includes`, so I uploaded `17763.diff` to `mysite/wp-includes'. 
3)I connected to the server via SSH, and changed directory to that directory  
4)I wrote the command:  $ patch < mods.diff  
5) and that was that!

Comment: if I don't have SSH, what can I do?